# how to index or loop through same class or tags in HTML to scrap information using selenium in python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, tags

```
<div data-v-482c44e2="" class="right" xpath="1">
  <span data-v-482c44e2="" class="views mr-1 v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small"        style="background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17); border-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);">
<span class="v-chip__content">
<i data-v-482c44e2="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-comment theme--dark" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
<span data-v-482c44e2="">**60**</span>
</span>
</span>
<span data-v-482c44e2="" class="views mr-1 v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small" style="background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17); border-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);">
<span class="v-chip__content">
<i data-v-482c44e2="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-eye theme--dark" style="font-size: 12px;"></i>
<span data-v-482c44e2="">**3712**</span>
</span>
</span>
<span data-v-482c44e2="" class="v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small" style="background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17); border-color: rgb(17, 17, 17);">
<span class="v-chip__content"><span data-v-482c44e2="">**51:16**</span></span></span><!----></div>
```

I can scrap the text "60" and "51:16" but cannot scrap the text "3712". And I want to scrap this text information?

I can scrap the text "60" and "51:16" but cannot scrap the text "3712". I am using the below code:

````
if result.find(class_="views mr-1 v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small"): # video-views
                        comments_count = result.find(class_="views mr-1 v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small").text.strip("\n").strip()
                        
                        print("comments_count: ", comments_count)
                        
                    if result.find(class_="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-eye theme--dark"): # video-views
                        view_count1 = result.find(class_="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-eye theme--dark").text.strip("\n").strip()
                        
                        print("view_count1: ", view_count1)
                        
                    if result.find(class_="v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small"): # video-views
                        duration = result.find(class_="v-chip v-chip--label theme--dark v-size--small").text.strip("\n").strip()
                        
                        print("duration: ", duration)```
````